# Can the Dart analyzer prevent compilation if I pass a particlar subclass as an argument to a method?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-analyzer

I am upgrading an older app from Flutter 2 to Flutter 3, and one problem I have encountered is that the `TextButton.icon()` goes crazy if `child` is a `Flexible`. This did not happen with `FlatButton.icon()`, which worked just fine.

So I'm wondering if there is a way to use the Dart analyzer to my advantage, to prevent the code from even compiling if I'm passing a `Flexible()` as a child to `TextButton.icon()` anywhere in the code?

I know that of course I can search and replace in the code, but I'm more interested to know if the Dart analyzer can be used to perform this kind of analysis somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [custom_lint](https://pub.dev/packages/custom_lint) package to write custom lints to do whatever you want.  It's a nice simplification (and documentation!) of the existing analyzer API, but apparently much easier to write it to do what you want.  You can even write "quick fixes" if you desire.